# Unable to connect to Hive from Eclipse

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, pom.xml

I'm new to Big Data/Hadoop. I'm trying to connect to Hive from Eclipse using JDBC. I keep getting the following error. I have no idea what's going on. Please help.

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
>   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/eragank/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.4.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/eragank/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>   Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Login failure for hive/mksd1dlllytj001.c.iron-potion-771.internal@IHGEXT.GLOBAL from keytab /etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:935) at com.ihg.test.Test.main(Test.java:32)
>   Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:897) at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:760)
>       at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:926)
>       ... 1 more

**Test.java**

```
package com.test.Test;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class Test {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws SQLException
 * @throws IOException 
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
      try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
      System.out.println("Class FOUND!!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
      org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new     org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
      conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
      UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
      UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("hive/mksd1dlllytj001.c.iron-potion-771.internal@IHGEXT.GLOBAL", "/etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab");
    //replace "hive" here with the name of the user the queries should run as
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://mksd1dlllytj001.c.iron-potion-771.internal:10000/grs_core?transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;auth=kerberos;sasl.qop=auth-int;principal=hive/mksd1dlllytj001.c.iron-potion-771.internal@IHGEXT.GLOBAL", "hive", "");
  //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://mksd1dlllytj001.c.iron-potion-771.internal:10000/;principal=hive/mksd1dlllytj001.c.iron-potion-771.internal@IHGEXT.GLOBAL;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice");
//    HiveDriver hd=new HiveDriver();
//   System.out.println("HDB CON..");
//   
//   Connection con2= hd.connect("jdbc:hive2://mksd1dlllytj001.c.iron-potion-771.internal:10000/grs_core?transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;auth=kerberos;sasl.qop=auth-int");
//   
//   System.out.println("HDB CONN="+con2);
//    
    //;principal=hive/node.addr@ABCREALM.LOCAL
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    /*String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
    stmt.execute("drop table if exists " + tableName);
    stmt.execute("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
    // show tables
    // String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'"; */    
    String sql = ("show tables;");
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString(1));
      }
  }
}
```

**POM.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ihg.ptfwork</groupId>
  <artifactId>ptfUpdateTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ptfUpdateTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <env.hiveVersion>1.2.1000.2.6.0.3-8</env.hiveVersion>
    <env.hivecoreDir>/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf</env.hivecoreDir>
    <env.hivecoreFile>hive-site.xml</env.hivecoreFile>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-beeline</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0_05</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies> 
</project>
```

Comment: What do you have in that _keytab_ file?? `klist -e -k xxxx.keytab`

Comment: Why don't you enable the debug trace, as explained in the GitBook _"Hadoop and Kerberos, the madness beyond the gate"_ section "low-level secrets" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to login without using `UserGroupInformation`, you should be able to connect simply using the  `DriverManager.getConnection()`, I do the same with an h2 database and it works fine. 
It sounds like it is an issue with the authentication process you are trying to use which I am not very familiar with.